# Problem with Tuning & Benchmark "surv.svm"

Tags: mlr3

I get different error messages when I try to tune/benchmark "surv.svm".

For tuning I get the following error
Error in kernelMatrix(Xtrain = sv, kernel_type = kernel_type, kernel_pars = kernel_pars,  :    additiv kernel can not be applied on constant column

For benchmark I get the following error when poly_kernel is listed
Error in tcrossprod(K, Dc) : non-conformable arguments

When poly_kernel is removed, I get different error message

What is the problem and how to solve it?

```
task = tsk("actg")

learner = as_learner(ppl("distrcompositor",
                         learner = lrn("surv.svm", type = "regression", 
                                        kernel    = to_tune(c("lin_kernel", "add_kernel", "rbf_kernel")),
                                        gamma.mu  = to_tune(p_dbl(-3, 1, trafo = function(x) 10^x))),
                     estimator = "kaplan", form = "ph"))

set.seed(82721)
inner_cv  = rsmp("cv", folds = 2) 

at_learner = AutoTuner$new(learner    = learner,
                           resampling = inner_cv,
                           measure    = msr("surv.cindex"),
                           terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 96),
                           tuner      = tnr("irace"))

at_learner$train(task)
```

Comment: This is apparently a problem with the data-set (you have a constant column as suggested by the error message)

Comment: Can you try running the same algorithm on a different task?